# A party of jealous guys

Tags: mathematics, graph-theory

I was really happy for the fact that I won the inter-galactic best magician award. So I decided to throw a party of $n$ people (excluding me).

The people who came to that party was *jealous, really jealous* of each other. Some people were not jealous of each other, but some - if not most - people, were. Jealousness, as y'all know, is mutual, so if $i$-th guy is jealous of $j$-th guy, then $j$-th guy is also jealous of the $i$-th guy.

After all the guys come, I form a special ritual called the *jealousy measuring ceremony* before the party: Every guy, to show off how they're good at jealousy, counts among the other $n-1$ guys total how many guys he's jealous of, and writes it down on a piece of paper and puts it inside a small green box which I prepared.

As it was a party of magicians, I brought $m$ different colored magician hats, total $n$ in number (there's at least one hat of each color) such that it's possible to put a hat on top of each of the guys, and no two persons $i$ and $j$ who are jealous of each other has the same colored hat on their head. Being the great tightwad that I am, I also ensured that $m$ is the smallest number with such property.

Now being the great magician that I am (didn't I mention that I'm also a brilliant hypnotist ?), I can pick two integers $(i,j)$ and perform a special move called wafoo: if $i$th guy and $j$ th guy are jealous of each other, remove the jealousy between them, or if they're not jealous, make them jealous of each other.

I perform a bunch of wafoo moves, and then perform the *jealousy measuring ceremony* again, this time using a blue box. I'll be the **wafoo-master** if the numbers on the paper in the green box is a permutation of the numbers of the papers in the blue box, and I can pick $m-1$ distinct integers $a_1, \cdots, a_{m-1}$ among $[1,n]$ such that for any $i \neq j \leq m-1$, the $a_i$ and $a_j$th guy are jealous of each other.

Can I always perform a sequence of wafoo moves to become the wafoo master, regardless of the initial distribution of the jealousy among the $n$ persons ?

---

(<s>If you're too lazy to read the above</s> In other words, if an undirected graph $G$ with $n$ vertices has degree sequence $\{d_1, d_2, d_3, \cdots, d_n\}$ and chromatic number $m$, prove it's always possible to construct a graph $G'$ with $n$ vertices with the same  degree sequence and with $K_{m-1} \subset G$ )

Comment: This seems to be a purely mathematical problem (it seems to require a graph-theoretical proof for a graph-theoretical claim), and as such, even the laboriously constructed story doesn't make it very puzzlingly. Puzzly. Puzzle-like. Well, you know what I mean.

Comment: @Bass I agree, reasoning about the underlying graph-theoretic concepts without the proper language would be impossible, unless the solution were simple. And I believe the proper term is *puzzlish*.

Comment: At least two 3k+rep users agree this seems to be a math problem, not a puzzle, and yet there are no votes to close it as such (and one of those two answered it anyway). Community members can, should, and are *encouraged* to use their voices *and their votes* to keep the site on topic and free from detritus. Please do so! (@Bass, $@$noedne)

Comment: @Rubio, it's the user's first post, and a lot of work has clearly gone into making it as puzzlificious as possible. If you want it closed, go ahead, but I don't want to greet a newcomer that way. We can, as a community, stomach a pure maths problem every once in a while, at least under such obvious attenuating circumstances. But maybe don't make a habit out of it, OP? :-)

Comment: @Rubio Apparently you can only ping one user per comment! I think that determining whether a math problem is sufficiently *puzzly* requires some idea of the solution. The user framed the problem in a puzzly manner, and as I briefly mentioned in my previous comment, a simple solution to the puzzle that, say, just required a few *wafoos* would be a great puzzle. However, as I write in my answer, I believe the claim as stated is false. If true, this should be grounds for closing, but I don't know if it would succeed given the mathiness of my counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

> The claim is false. Let $n=15$ and $G$ be the complement of the disjoint union of $3$ $5$-cycles. The chromatic number of $G$ is the sum of the chromatic numbers of (the complements of) the $5$-cycles, which are $3$, so $m=9$. Let $G'$ be any graph with $n$ vertices and the same degree sequence as $G$. In $\overline{G'}$, the complement of $G'$, every vertex has degree $2$, so $\overline{G'}$ is a disjoint union of cycles. The clique number of $G'$ is the sum of the independence numbers of these cycles, which are at most half their orders, so $\omega(G')\le\frac{15}2<8=m-1$.